# How to separate text messages by new lines?

Tags: c#, arrays, email, smtp

I noticed that if I send a text message via email it will only allow 159 characters. (I think this is dues to smtp)

Some of the messages I am sending are longer than 159 characters, I could just but the sting and send it that way but I would prefer to send the messages separated by new lines.

Here is an example of my text message:

```
    (Need Bid)Salesman: Firstname Lastname
    Customer: CustFirstname CustLastname
    Customer Address: 1111 TheSteetAdd St, Lockport, New York 12124
    Customer Number: 111-222-3333
    Apt Date/Time: 1/17/2021 5:00 PM
```

The text in the parentheses is the subject line. So that could also change its total string count.
For each one of these text messages I am also adding "\r\n" so it will make a nice new line for the users.

Here is an example of how I would like this method to preform. I don't want to just randomly sperate the sting, I would like it to be by the new lines.

```
    (1/2)
    (Need Bid)Salesman: Firstname Lastname
    Customer: CustFirstname CustLastname
    Customer Address: 1111 TheSteetAdd St, Lockport, New York 12124
    
    (2/2)
    Customer Number: 111-222-3333
    Apt Date/Time: 1/17/2021 5:00 PM
```

```
        {
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com", "Firstname Lastname");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("1112223333@vtext.com", "Firstname Lastname");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            MailAddress bcc = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com");
            message.Bcc.Add(bcc);
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("stuff", 26);
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            Debug.WriteLine("Sending an email message to {0} and {1}.",
                to.DisplayName, message.Bcc.ToString());

            var totalMessage = message.Subject + message.Body;

            //See if message is longer than 159 characters, if so send in another message
            if (message.Subject.Count() + message.Body.Count() > 159)
            {

                var splitBodyByNewLine = message.Body.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                string[] arrayOfMessages = new string[] { };
                string currentString;

                int totalStingCount = message.Subject.Count();

                foreach (string aString in splitBodyByNewLine)
                {
                    var tempChecker = aString.Count();
                    var tempCheckerBPlusS = totalStingCount + aString.Count();

                    if (arrayOfMessages.Length == 0)
                    {
                        if (totalStingCount + aString.Count() < 159)
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else if (aString.Count() < 159)
                    {

                    }
                }


                Debug.WriteLine("");
            }

            try
            {
                client.Send(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateBccTestMessage(): {0}",
                    ex.ToString());
            }

            
        }
```

Comment: A 159 character limit in a email message text would a serious limitation. I can't imagine any smtp server in the world that have this kind of limits.

Comment: Imagine in any email account... Each text paragraph in a new email, that would be funny.

Comment: The SMTP protocol specifies to allow AT LEAST 64k octets (bytes). You can read it [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.7).

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Why did you remove your post?

Comment: @iPhoenix_ do not get me wrong, I was thinking to help you with my answer, but at the same time I can see it does not bring value. My other question to you, in your input in your question, I do not see ## OR ?<=\r\n And the max character was 159, my point did all that change in your answer? Just was curious. But you get my up vote for your question.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Thanks for the upvote.

I changed it from 159 to 140 just bc I had to account for the [subject] + [currentMessageCounter] (in my example it was "(Need Bid) (1/2)"). So I just gave myself a safe buffer (yes 140 is not the exact number), I know special characters count for more then 1 vs a normal string character.

I am using ## as a place holder until I group the strings. Then at the end I am removing anything before ## bc SMTP sends the subject separately from the body.

"(?<=\r\n)" just made it easier to account for the strings as I was evaluating. Agreed, not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking time to account for all the scenarios and edge cases here was my solution.

```
public static List<string> MessageSplitter(string splitterSubject, string splitterBody)
    {
        var splitBodyByNewLine = Regex.Split(splitterBody, @"(?<=\r\n)").Where(s => s != String.Empty);

        List<string> unGroupedStings = new List<string>();
        List<string> GroupedMessages = new List<string>();

        int maxMessageCount = 140;
        int currentStingCount = 0;

        foreach (string aString in splitBodyByNewLine)
        {
            if (unGroupedStings.Count() == 0 && GroupedMessages.Count() == 0 && currentStingCount == 0)
            {
                if (splitterSubject.Count() + aString.Count() < maxMessageCount)
                {
                    unGroupedStings.Add(splitterSubject + "##" + aString);

                    currentStingCount = splitterSubject.Count() + aString.Count();
                }
            }
            else if (currentStingCount + aString.Count() < maxMessageCount)
            {
                if (aString == splitBodyByNewLine.Last())
                {
                    unGroupedStings.Add(aString);

                    string lastTempSting = string.Join("", unGroupedStings);
                    string lastTempSting2 = lastTempSting.Remove(0, lastTempSting.IndexOf("##") + 2);

                    GroupedMessages.Add(lastTempSting2);
                    unGroupedStings.Clear();
                    currentStingCount = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    unGroupedStings.Add(aString);
                    currentStingCount = currentStingCount + aString.Count();
                }
            }
            else if (currentStingCount + aString.Count() > maxMessageCount)
            {
                string tempSting = string.Join("", unGroupedStings);
                string tempSting2 = tempSting.Remove(0, tempSting.IndexOf("##") + 2);

                GroupedMessages.Add(tempSting2);
                unGroupedStings.Clear();
                unGroupedStings.Add(splitterSubject + "##" + aString);
                currentStingCount = aString.Count();
            }

            if (splitterBody == string.Join("", GroupedMessages))
            {
                //this is just a check to make sure messages have been separated correctly and matches the original
            }
        }
        return GroupedMessages;
    }
```

Here is the syntax to use the method.

```
if (subject.Count() + body.Count() > 159)
        {
            MultiMessage = MessageSplitter(subject, body);

            int messageCount = 1;

            foreach (string eachMessage in MultiMessage)
            {
                //Send your message

                //I am using messageCount++ to label each message 
                //Here is the sample code
                //$" ({messageCount}/{MultiMessage.Count()})\r\n" + eachMessage

                messageCount++;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("", MultiMessage));
        }
```

Output

```
(Need Bid) (1/2)
Salesman: Firstname Lastname
Customer: CustFirstname CustLastname
Customer Address: 1111 TheSteetAdd St, Lockport, New York 12124

(Need Bid) (2/2)
Customer Number: 111-222-3333
Apt Date/Time: 1/17/2021 5:00 PM
```

Hope this helps someone one day!

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question, find it as little challenge. I have not taken your code in consideration, and have a solution from scratch.

How does it work, we need to split lines because you need messages pr. lines and at the same time each message should not exceed 159 characters. We go through that process and check the remain text in the lines, if they are less than 159 characters we take the rest and stop.

So lets go to the code.

Hers is your given input:

```
var fullMsg = "(Need Bid)Salesman: Firstname Lastname\r\n" +
              "Customer: CustFirstname CustLastname\r\n" +
              "Customer Address: 1111 TheSteetAdd St, Lockport, New York 12124\r\n" +
              "Customer Number: 111 - 222 - 3333\r\n" +
              "Apt Date/ Time: 1 / 17 / 2021 5:00 PM\r\n";
```

Now we create a method to take our message, the code is self explanation:

```
public static List<string> CreateSmallMessages(string fullMsg)
{
    const int MAX_STR = 159;
    var lines = fullMsg.Split("\r\n");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();
    int wordsCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        wordsCount += lines[i].Length;
        sb.Append(lines[i] + "\r\n");

        if (wordsCount + lines[i + 1].Length >= MAX_STR)
        {
            wordsCount = 0;
            messages.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }

        if (RemainWords(lines.Skip(i).ToArray()) < MAX_STR)
        {
            var remainText = new string(lines.Skip(i + 1).SelectMany(e => $"{e}\r\n").ToArray());
            messages.Add(remainText);
            break;
        }
    }

    return messages;
}

public static int RemainWords(string[] lines)
{
    return lines.SelectMany(e => e).Count();
}
```

Lets now try it out in main method:

```
var messages = CreateSmallMessages(fullMsg);

for (var i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"({i + 1}/{messages.Count})");
    Console.WriteLine(messages[i]);
}
```

This will give us following output:

```
(1/2)
(Need Bid)Salesman: Firstname Lastname
Customer: CustFirstname CustLastname
Customer Address: 1111 TheSteetAdd St, Lockport, New York 12124

(2/2)
Customer Number: 111 - 222 - 3333
Apt Date/ Time: 1 / 17 / 2021 5:00 PM
```

Now you can make a loop to send each message separately, that part is left to you.

Note: I am pretty sure the code can be improved and optimized, but this is a conceptual answer to show how I would do it, and you are welcome to push it further to next level.

Comment: Like you said this is the conceptual answer, I am looking for a full solution. There are so many things not accounted for in this answer. I am working on a full solution now.